# After setting com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow, how can I make holding ⌥ re-enable shadows?

Tags: screen-capture, defaults, big-sur

If you hold `⌥` (option) while taking a window screenshot macOS, it excludes the window's drop shadow in the saved image.

You can change default behavior to *always* hide shadows with

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true
```

However, this makes `⌥` key do nothing when taking a screenshot, at least on Big Sur in my testing. Is there a way make window shadows hidden by default, but *enabled* if I hold ⌥ while taking a screenshot?